How to calculate an appropriate pension withdrawal rate?
I'm trying to create a pension prediction spreadsheet for myself. One of the input variables is going to be the pension withdrawal rate. Looking around the web, I can see that typically folks are recommend to make this in the 3-4% range; for example, Investopedia recommends that. This generally seems to just be a fixed number which doesn't vary according to any other criteria.
However, surely the withdrawal rate should depend on the age at which I retire (which is also an input to my spreadsheet). If I retire early (e.g. 55 rather than the "standard"/state retirement age where I live - the UK - which is 68), shouldn't the withdrawal rate be quite a bit lower to avoid running out of money?
Should I / how can I calculate an appropriate withdrawal rate? If there a standard formula I can use? I've searched the web quite a bit, but I can't find anything appropriate which isn't completely impenetrable except for dyed-in-the-wool professionals.

Some calculations here.

The 4% number is a conservative figure chosen because it's less than typical investment growth rates, so theoretically you are living only on the growth and the money can last "forever".
Actual growth is likely to be higher, but this continuous draw may not account for emergency spending, or the investments may do badly for a while (see comments elsewhere about maintaining a year's reserve in cash form to avoid having to sell low), so the caution is appropriate.
There are tools which will help you model what may happen to your money given some base assumptions. I use the one built into my personal finance program, but your investment agent may offer one or there are others. It's very much a rough guess, since you are trying to predict future spending and income, but it's a good sanity check. Mine reports that, in today's dollars (accounting for also-guessed inflation) my net worth without selling the house should stay basically constant until end-of-life costs, which may wipe out most of that cash. That was my goal when saving for retirement, and I'm quite happy to have hit it.

This makes a lot of sense to me actually - that your withdrawal rate is running 'under' the typical rate of growth. I wish one of the sources I found had explained it that simply!

I've made extensive spreadsheets but they depend a lot on your specific situation, your goals and the underlying assumptions. Factors that are important include

How much money have you invested
How much more will you earn and/or invest before you start withdrawing
What other source of income do you have and when do they kick in (social security, pensions, option, side gig, etc)
What is your assumed rate of return, how well do you deal with risk
What is inflation
How much money do will you be needing and how will this change over time as you grow older
What does your health care situation look like
How long are you and your partner (if applicable) are planning on living.

Turns out that many of these things are either unknowable or very difficult to get even remotely right, so I found the values of these spreadsheets to be fairly limited.
The 4% is just a rough rule of thumb that works in many "normal" cases. You can try to work up an individual spreadsheet, but it's a fair bit of work and since many of the assumptions are shaky, it may not offer more confidence. I found the main value to be the insight that I gained on how things interact with each other and in a "sensitivity" analysis: what are the factors and assumption that matter the most (and you should keep an eye on).

I think these are all good factors to look at when doing overall retirement planning, yes. They still don't really explain how the typical 4% figure is arrived at or why it's what it is (see other answer), but this is a good checklist of things that any retirement calculation needs to include, I would agree. Thanks.

The tools I've used are basically this spreadsheet in a prettier form. You still need to enter best guess information, for a inflation and income. And allow for the occasional unexpected major expense when figuring out your budget, and all you can really expect from them is to give you some sense of how confident you should be that your plan is good enough to be comfortable with. Or at least is the best you can do at this time, and might indicate whether you want to work on adjusting your spending plans or finding more income.
